# Position layouts inside list items

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have a list and I want on the left part of a list item to show an image and on the right of the image
a series of widgets aligned vertically, one of which is an include:@layout
Having a relative layout I can add widgets using layout to right of the pic but:
1) I can not align the linear layout to the right of pic as there seems to be no such attribute
2) Without nesting the widgets in a linear layout and placing them only just to the right of the pick and one of top of the other I can not place the include:@layout where I want as it does not have a layout_bellow etc attribute.
How can I create such layouts?

**Update:**

```
++++++++ ++++++++++++++++++++
+IMAGE +  TEXTVIEW          +
+         +   LAYOUT FILE   +
+         +         TEXTVIEW+
+++++++++++++++++++ TEXTVIEW+
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumb"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/friend_name”
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:gravity="top"
       />


    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/stub_friend_status”
        android:inflatedId="@+id/friend_status”
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumb"
        android:layout_below="@id/friend_name"
        android:layout="@layout/friend_status”/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latest_date”
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/stub_friend_status"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/thumb"
       />


    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/stub_general_info”
        android:inflatedId="@+id/general”
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/latest_date"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout="@layout/general_info”/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Posting an image of exactly what you want would be helpful. Maybe even the xml you have tried so far.

Comment: @codeMagic:Please see update. As for my xml it is not doing anything.

Comment: @codeMagic:I tried view stubs but it seems that they don't align properly

Comment: @codeMagic:Aligning bellow a viewstub seems to have no effect

Comment: I don't understand, " I can not align the linear layout to the right of pic as there seems to be no such attribute". If it is inside of a `RelativeLayout` then you can use `android:layout_toRightOf`

Comment: @codeMagic:See example in OP. They all cram up to the top like view stub is ignored

Answer (score 1):

Here is layout, you can make left/right part equally, left part put image and right part you can put layout vertically:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    //left part
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_frame"
            android:layout_width="img_width"
            android:layout_height="img_height"
            android:gravity="center"
            >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/your_img"/>

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    //right part
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        >


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/view_1"
               ... ...
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/view_2"
            ... ...
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />

            ... ...            

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want left part smaller than right, then you can change the `layout_weight` of left/right as 1/2 or 2/3 ...

Hope this help!

Comment: I tried it, the only issue I have is that it leaves a margin to the left of the image. What I had (that was not working properly) was a the image inside a relative layout with android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" and so there was no space to the left. How can I fix this with your approach?

Comment: `no space to the left`? then you can put margin to left you want

Comment: And also you can adjust the width and height of `FrameLayout` to suit your screen